# Apollo Server: how to post-process all `id: ID` fields without directives?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, graphql-tools

Our schema looks like this:

```
type Product {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}

type User {
  id: ID!
  firstName: String!
}
```

The backend returns auto-increment IDs, we want to prefix them by type and currently, we're using directives for that:

```
type Product {
  id: ID! @uniqueID
  name: String!
}

type User {
  id: ID! @uniqueID
  firstName: String!
}
```

```js
class UniqueIdDirective extends SchemaDirectiveVisitor {
  visitFieldDefinition(...) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Is there a way to avoid adding `@uniqueID` everywhere and just depend on the `ID` type? In other words, is it possible to write a schema visitor against our original schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible, via `mapSchema`. It has been answered here: https://github.com/ardatan/graphql-tools/discussions/2126.